# "Aggressive Amount" of something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

So, I'm looking for a word or phrase that might mean "an aggressive amount". To explain, I'm trying to find a word or phrase that might mean an excessive amount of something, delivered with force, or somewhat chaotically.

For example, a burst dam - the water would flow out in a huge wave; both excessive and with a huge amount of force.

Comment: Have you tried looking up synonyms for 'flood' and 'surge'?

Comment: See [Schlock Mercenary](https://www.schlockmercenary.com/) for occasional references to ***overkill*** and other ways to say ***copious amounts of*** *\*ahem\** ***diplomacy*** …

Comment: "Amount" itself can never be "aggressive" -- it's the flow that can be.

Answer (score 1):

Torrent may be an option.  It works specifically for water but can also apply to almost anything.

Comment: How is the word defined? Can you please cite the source?

Comment: Torrent - a tumultuous outpouring; a violent stream of liquid.  Merriam-Webter